# How do I define a babel dialect of an existing language?

Tags: babel

I would like to define a dialect of an existing language, without modifying the existing LDF file. I have, as an example, `foo.ldf`:

```
\ProvidesLanguage{foo}
        [2017/09/20 v0.1 Foo support for babel]
\input english.ldf\relax
\adddialect\l@foo\l@british
\endinput
```

When I try to process the document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[foo]{babel}

\begin{document}
Some text in foo.
\end{document}
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \l@foo 
l.192 \ldf@finish\CurrentOption
```

I've studied the Babel manual and source code and searched online extensively, but I can't find an example of a "3rd-party dialect" definition, or work out how to do this without either copying and modifying `english.ldf`, or making a new LDF.

Comment: What do you want to change? Unfortunately there is not a simple way to define a dialect, except by copying and modifying an existing ldf file.

Comment: @JavierBezos, thanks for confirming that. I want to define "18th century English" and use that a) directly, to change punctuation spacing, and b) indirectly, to drive `csquotes` styles and font selection (to use long S's).